# How to create file at specified directory with touch command

Tags: linux, touch

In Linux the `touch`-command creates files. But it always creates it in the current directory. How can I create files in a specified directory?

For example

```
touch file ../my_directory
```

Comment: Isn't this a SuperUser question?

Comment: it is not superuser question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
touch ../my_directory/file
```

it won't create ../my_directory though, but I think this is not what you asked for.

Comment: That would be quite handy.

This one:
    mkdir -p ../your_directory ; touch ../your_directory/file
does the trick, but it lacks some Élégance.